# .NetCore App Memory Leak - high Overhead|Unused memory

Tags: .net-core, memory, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, clr

Working on a .Net Core app that reads data from source, transforms it, stores in in-memory queue, batches transformed data and writes it to a sink. As the process runs for a longer time, we observe that the memory of the VM starts decreasing until it is completely over, and I start getting "Out-of-memory" exceptions. We monitored the in-memory queue in the program, there is no data piling up there. I created a memory dump of the program from "Task Manager".

[image]
Most of the memory seems to be in Overhead|Unused. What does this mean? How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of the .NET Core? Could you use a tool showing sizes of teh generations and LOH, including fragmentation? I'd start from recording "gc collect only" session in PerfView.

Comment: net5.0 is the version. Will the .etl file do?

Comment: Looks very interesting, will dig it and return with some details!

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me when the gc mode was server. In  this mode the GC collects memory in much bigger chunks, so it might take a while until GC starts collecting memory. In my case the process reached around 20GB. When I changed to workstation mode the process reached around 1GB of memory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/garbage-collector#workstation-vs-server